# How to correctly implement Google Authenticator

Tags: php, authentication, google-authenticator

How to correctly implement Google Authenticator

I am trying to wrap my head around Google Authenticator implementation. I want to be able to replicate the iPhone google authenticator app, in other words I want my own app that spits out my gmail verification codes the same way that my iPhone app does it. I tried out this library that I can’t make it to work or there could be something I was doing incorrectly. https://github.com/PHPGangsta/GoogleAuthenticator

Here are the steps I’ve taken:

```
1 - Went to accounts.google.com and scanned my barcode using my iPhone
2 - Saved the secret key
3 - And using the PHPGangsta library, generate 6 digit code with secret key 
4 - Use code to sign in to my google account
5 - Sign in Failed 
6 - Me sad
```

Here is my code:

```
<?php
require_once 'GoogleAuthenticator.php';

$ga = new PHPGangsta_GoogleAuthenticator();

$secret = 'mysecretkey1209312310293';

echo "Secret is: ".$secret."\n\n";

//not sure if this qrCodeUrl thing matters
$qrCodeUrl = $ga->getQRCodeGoogleUrl('my@google.com', $secret); 

echo "Google Charts URL for the QR-Code: ".$qrCodeUrl."\n\n";

$oneCode = $ga->getCode($secret);

echo "Checking Code '$oneCode' and Secret '$secret':\n";

$checkResult = $ga->verifyCode($secret, $oneCode, 2);    // 2 = 2*30sec clock tolerance
if ($checkResult) {
    echo 'OK';
} else {
    echo 'FAILED';
}
```